# Change android keyboard language to hindi on button click

Tags: android, android-softkeyboard, android-input-method

In my app, I want to open keyboard with Hindi language. I tried this-

```
    String languageToLoad  = "in"; // your language
    Locale locale = new Locale(languageToLoad); 
    Locale.setDefault(locale);
    Configuration config = new Configuration();
    config.locale = locale;
    getBaseContext().getResources().updateConfiguration(config, 
    getBaseContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
```

But its not helping me, as the keyboard still remains in english language.

Comment: It will update app layout language from english to arabic , not the keyboard language.

Answer (score 2):

You need to change this

```
String languageToLoad  = "hi_IN";
```

Comment: Ok it works, but only when the user has already selected the Google Hindi Keyboard from the setting. Is their any way to select that Hindi Language keyboard programmatically ?

Comment: I guess it boils down to this: Change User selected Locale "programatically", without User's notice. Not sure if Android will allow it to happen.